# Not able to open the image in new activity

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Need help. It may be weird.

First activity has listview(like lazyadapter) once i click the list it opens a new activity with description, title and image. But iam not able to display the image. Not sure how to send it ...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
String pdate = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdate)).getText().toString();
//ImageView thumb = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image));

// Starting new intent
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_PLAYER, title);
    in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, R.id.list_image);
    in.putExtra(KEY_TRANSACTION, description);
    in.putExtra(KEY_PUBDATE, pdate);
    startActivity(in);  }
```

My Second activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent in = getIntent();

    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_PLAYER);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TEXT);
    String pdate = in.getStringExtra(KEY_PUBDATE);
    String thumb_image = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);

    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);
    TextView lblPdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pubdate_label);
    ImageView thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_label);

    lblName.setText(title);
    thumb.setImageURI(Uri.parse(thumb_image));
    lblDesc.setText(description);
    lblPdate.setText(pdate);
```

Comment: are you able to set image directly from resources on Second Activity? Not From getStringExtra..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int thumb_image = in.getIntExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
thumb.setImageResource(thumb_image);
```

You are passing in a resource ID (an integer) to your intent. When you receive that intent, you extract it using `getIntExtra` which will give you the value of `R.id.list_image`. Then you may call `setImageResource` on your ImageView to set the image.

Calling `getStringExtra` when you passed in an integer will result in a null string.

Comment: Great !! Thanks guys !! This shows no errors !! I am new to android so this is something new for me ... I dont see the image in the new activity ...    i am seeing the below in the logcat                                W/ImageView(5381): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050034}

Comment: R.id.list_image is likely a resource ID for a View (imageview, textview, etc). To pass an ID for an actual image it would be something like R.drawable.image;  obviously the "image" would be whatever you named your file when you placed it in your drawable folder

Comment: Thanks Dymmeh and Perroloco for all your help!! That Works !! Bingo :)